# EAR application works on Websphere8.5 but refuses to work on Websphere liberty 16.0.0.4

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, websphere, ear, websphere-liberty

I get in inheritance [EAR application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_(file_format)) which I need to continue to develop. The problem that I can't cause it work on [Websphere Liberty 16.0.0.4](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2016/12/13/new-release-websphere-liberty-16-0-0-4/) while on Websphere Application Server Full Profile 8.5 it works fine.  Unfortunately or (fortunately :) ) my working station is Macbook Pro, and WAS Full Profile can't be installed on OSX (can't find links right now, but have done some search and find enough evidences for it) so I need to use VirtualBox with Linux or try to run this app on Liberty.

The latest solution doesn't work so well for me, I get the following error:

> [ERROR   ] CWWJP0012E: The persistence unit name is not specified and
>   a unique persistence unit is not found in the BigEnterpriseAppEAR
>   application and BigEnterpriseAppEJB.jar module. [ERROR   ] CWWJP0029E:
>   The server cannot find the  persistence unit in the
>   BigEnterpriseAppEJB.jar module and the BigEnterpriseAppEAR
>   application. [ERROR   ] CWNEN0035E: The java:comp/env/BigEnterpriseApp
>   reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the DataProvider
>   component in the BigEnterpriseAppEJB.jar module of the
>   BigEnterpriseAppEAR application cannot be resolved. [ERROR   ]
>   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during
>   invocation of method "getDataByOwner" on bean
>   "BeanId(BigEnterpriseAppEAR#BigEnterpriseAppWEB.war#DataAPI, null)". 
>   Exception data: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: nested
>   exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException:   The
>   java:comp/env/BigEnterpriseApp reference of type
>   javax.persistence.EntityManager for the DataProvider component in the
>   BigEnterpriseAppEJB.jar module of the BigEnterpriseAppEAR application
>   cannot be resolved.

The app is pretty simple `EAR` = `JPA` + `EJB` + `WAR`

**I don't know which configuration files would be helpful, so just write in a comments what to post and I will do it.**

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE 1:

`server.xml` file:

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
         <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
         <feature>ejbLite-3.1</feature>
         <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
         <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
         <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
         <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
         <feature>cdi-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm">
        <!-- <user name="yourUserName" password="" />  -->
    </basicRegistry>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>


    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

    <library id="DB2JCC4Lib">
         <fileset dir="/Users/anatoly/developer/sql_drivers" includes="*.jar"/>
    </library>

    <dataSource id="db2_slc" jndiName="jdbc/BEADB" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
            <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DB2JCC4Lib"/>
            <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="beadb" password="********" portNumber="50000" serverName="db2server" user="db2username"/>
    </dataSource>

    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="******"/>

    <enterpriseApplication id="BigEnterpriseAppEAR" location="BigEnterpriseAppEAR.ear" name="BigEnterpriseAppEAR"/>
</server>
```

`persistence.xml` file, located in **BigEnterpriseAppJPA > src > META-INF > persistence.xml**

in packaged EAR `persistence.xml` located in **BigEnterpriseAppEAR -> BigEnterpriseAppJPA.jar -> META-INF -> persistence.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="BigEnterpriseApp">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/BEADB</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.bea.entities.System</class>
        <class>com.bea.entities.Data</class>
        <class>com.bea.entities.User</class>
        <class>com.bea.entities.Group</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="BEADB" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionRetainMode" value="transaction" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: A good start would be to post your server.xml and persistence.xml.

Comment: @FRowe, done. Thank you!

Comment: What's the location of persistence.xml?

Comment: it's located in:  `BigEnterpriseAppJPA > src > META-INF > persistence.xml`

Comment: What's the location of persistence.xml in the packaged EAR?  The Liberty profile strictly interprets the location per the JPA spec while the full profile accepts non-standard locations.

Comment: In packaged EAR, you mean EAR when I compile to before deploy? If yes, the location as following: `BigEnterpriseAppEAR -> BigEnterpriseAppJPA.jar -> META-INF -> persistence.xml`

Comment: I suspect that the initialisation of the PU is failing because you have not yet set up a DataSource in your WAS Liberty instance corresponding to `jdbc/BEADB` (as referenced in the persistence.xml).

Comment: @SteveC, datasource has been set, there's `server.xml` in main post, also I checked all the settings multiple times. I think that I will try to create a clean project with the same configuration from a scratch and then just compare configuration files, line by line. At lease once it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

> [ERROR ] CWWJP0012E: The persistence unit name is not specified and a unique persistence unit is not found in the BigEnterpriseAppEAR application and BigEnterpriseAppEJB.jar module.

This would imply your persistence.xml roots are not at the legal locations defined by the JPA spec, section 8.2:

> In Java EE environments, the root of a persistence unit must be one of the following:
>
> - an EJB-JAR file
> - the WEB-INF/classes directory of a WAR file[87]
> - a jar file in the WEB-INF/lib directory of a WAR file
> - **a jar file in the EAR library directory**
> - an application client jar file
>
> NOTE: Java Persistence 1.0 supported use of a jar file in the root of the EAR as the root of a
>   persistence unit. This use is no longer supported. Portable applications should use the EAR
>   library directory for this case instead

Your setup seems to be trying to use **#4**?

> **BigEnterpriseAppEAR -> BigEnterpriseAppJPA.jar -> META-INF -> persistence.xml**

**BigEnterpriseAppJPA.jar** should be placed inside your EAR library directory. I believe this will be **BigEnterpriseAppEAR/lib** by default, but you can configure this with your /META-INF/**application.xml** in the EAR

Also note, that the persistence-unit name must be unique. Make sure that all persistence-unit names are not using the same name.